# using multiples addMethod jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I want to customize the validations of my form using the addMethod function with the jQuery validator, but when I tried to add more than one method the validator seems to look only at the first one.

Here is the code:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("name", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]{2,30}$/.test(value);
  }, "please enter a valid name");

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("surname", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]{1,30}\-?[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]{1,30}$/.test(value);
  }, "please enter a valid surname");

  $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
      firstname:{
        required: true,
        name: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 30
      },
      lastname:{
        required: true,
        surname: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 30        
      }
    }
  });
```

The issue is that on the last name I want to be able to add an '-' in case of a combined surname, I tried the regEx and it works exactly as I want to, but even if I call the method 'surname' in the rules of the field, it seems to elaborate the method 'name' anyway!

Thanks in advance for your help, I really don't understand what I'm missing here..

https://jsfiddle.net/2zumkcyg/11/

Comment: You should accept @dysfunc answer (you can change it)... I realise that I misread your question. But keep in mind the debugging trick ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your method name. The prop `name` inside rules is already a predefined rule inside `$.validator` like `minLength`. If you change `name` to anything but that it will work.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.validator.addMethod("named", function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]{2,30}$/.test(value);
  }, "Please enter a valid name.");

  $.validator.addMethod("surname", function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]{1,30}\-?[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]{1,30}$/.test(value);
  }, "Please enter a valid surname.");

  $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
      firstname: {
        required: true,
        named: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 30
      },
      lastname:{
        required: true,
        surname: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 30        
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2zumkcyg/25/)

Comment: The demo doesn't produce the same output. @LouysPatriceBessette When the field is invalid it returns the proper error message. The dev is not trying to intentionally override the name method. They will have to add `name: false` to every new rule now.